# split JSON data from PHP to three arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am passing values from PHP Script to JS using JSON encode.

```
$arr=array('X'=>$X,'Y'=>$Y,'par'=>$par);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Which produces

```
{"X": ["-0.9537121038646844","-0.9537121038646844","-0.9537121038646844","0.9537121038646843",""],
 "Y": ["-0.9537121038646844","-0.7799936811949519","-0.5533396521383813","-0.37962122946864896",null],
 "par": ["0.009811016749950838","0.005007306592216437","5.058030686503405E-4","9.451402320405391E-4",null]}
```

In the javascript, I used the following command

```
{
   $.post("plot.php",param,function(data){dataType:"json";console.log(data);Var X1=data.X;});
}
```

But I am not able to obtain the values of X alone. I tried few suggestions from similar threads, but none of them did the trick.I need the three arrays, X,Y and Par to be used in JS.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.post("plot.php", param, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var X1 = data.X;
  },
  "json"
);
```

You can also use $.ajax (which is the function $.post internally calls):

```
{
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "plot.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: param,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      var X1=data.X;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: indeed, your datatype is in your success fucntion for some reeason

Comment: When I tried your suggestion, my console.log(X1) doesnt print the X1. I am using firebug. Any insight on what could be happening ? 
Thanks.

Comment: Try `console.log(data)`, do you get any output?

Comment: I do get data on the console. I have pasted the data as a part of the question. Just that am not able to separate the data into X,Y and par individually.

Comment: @SaiSudharsanan In which format do you get the data in the console? Is it a string or a JSON object? If it is a string, which MIME type does your server serve for your URI?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using php you have to specify at the last parameter of post fn that is json type:

```
$.post("plot.php",param, function(data){ 
 console.log(data);
 var X1=data.X;
},'json');
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had tried this. Yet I am not sure if this works. My console.log(X1) doesnt even print X1.I am using firefox browser and firebug. 
Thanks, 
Sai